# Merge shp in QGIS with different fields

Tags: qgis, shapefile

There is a way to merge shp polygon with different fields? or there is a tool to copy the fields and format from one shp to another (not the content)?

Answer (score 1):

Under QGIS 3.4.x: `Vector -> Data management tools -> Merge vector layers`.

Uses all attributes and all features.

Comment: Thats is maybe in ArcGis, in QGIS 3.4.x (spanish version) only I can select the layers to merge.

Comment: Yeah, and you asked about merging layers.

Comment: ohh sorry my mistake I'm QGIS user... sorry about confusion!!

Comment: The confusion is not the software, it's what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it with Refactor Fields, then I can Merge the layers. With that tool I can rebuild the atributes table with other shape file format.

Thanks to everyone.